# What does "if you don't have one, you don't need the other" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

This is from the TV series [House M.D.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412142/)

> Cameron: He got you to us.
>
> Marina: He never gave up, no matter what happened. He kept saying to me
>   don't worry, we will make it, I will take care of you. He refuses to worry
>   or pray, he believes **if you don't have one, you don't need the other**.

The actual transcript:

> Marina: He never gave up, no matter what happen [sic], he kept saying to me
>   don't worry, we will make it, I take [sic] care of you. He refuses to worry
>   or pray, he believe [sic] if you don't have one, you don't need the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the *to worry or pray*. *One* refers to *worry* and *the other* to *pray*.

What he means with that is that if you do not have worries, you do not need to pray. He refuses to worry, which means that he does not have any worries and that he has no need for prayers.

Comment: The text as originally cited was obviously somewhat inaccurate, and we have no link to the full original context, but since I assume the script was written by competent native speaker I think it's an unlikely juxtaposition. The initial references are to ***verbs** (to worry, to pray)*, so it seems clumsy in the extreme to couple these with a "stock phrase" that specifically depends on referencing ***nouns*** (which in this case strongly implies pluralising *a worry* as well as transparently converting from *to pray* to *prayer*).

Comment: The quote is from the episode Human Error, and the character Marina and her husband are Cuban, so the script writers may be deliberating using phrasing that a native English speaker wouldn't use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I took the nouns to be *worry*, and *prayer*.